# Reactjs: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I have to handle change in my datePicker

> It displays this error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen
>   when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate
>   or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

I have tried onUpdate={()=>handleUpdate()} but still showing the same error .

```
onUpdate={handleUpdate}
  const handleUpdate = (startDate, endDate) => {
    console.log(startDate, endDate)
    const { expData } = props
    const validDateStart = moment(startDate.timestamp).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
    const validDateEnd = moment(endDate.timestamp).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
    expData['startDate'] = validDateStart
    expData['endDate'] = validDateEnd
    setvisibleDatePicker(false)
  }
```

Comment: Have you some code in componentWillUpdate or in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: no, I did not use both of this

Comment: using any useEffect function ?

Comment: what do you have in your function setvisibleDatePicker(false)?

Comment: @pageNotfoUnd no

Comment: @Nemer it is a simple set State of a boolean value

Comment: `onUpdate={()=>handleUpdate()}` this should be the fix if not issue is somewhere else .This code seems fine

Comment: can you explain this error when happened? it is when you click on datePicker or when you choosing a date?

Comment: I think the reason you should use onChange instead of onUpdate because you said setvisibleDatePicker(false), setState will update the component again and your datePicker will update again and again.